# MonoGame - Project Layout and Structure (Architecture)

Tags: architecture, game-engine, projects-and-solutions, monogame

So I am trying my hand at some new skills, and want to build a simple game.

I am `C#` programmer by occupation and as with all projects, be it web or forms development, they all have some sort of structure to it.

I like doing things right the first time, and want to know if there are similar structured approaches to Game development using MonoGame. I tried searching, but I obviously do not speak the lingo.

The only things I have figured so far are separating assets using the content pipeline projects, but it all kinda feels a bit messy doing everything else in the one Game Application.

Ideally I would like to have a Windows Game, but easily ported to other OS's, and obviously in doing this I need to separate certain logic.

I found that there are may tutorials out there teaching me about sprites and "hello world" games, so I reckon that I will find all the help I need, if only I knew what to search for.

Any ideas, suggestions and links would be appreciated, I'll even up-vote answers that will give me terms used in the gaming development arena.

**UPDATE**

I came across the following so far:

- http://nic-gamedev.blogspot.com/2011/11/lets-make-game-engine-for-xna-40r-part.html
- http://xnagpa.net/xna4rpg.php (nice read and well laid out)

Comment: Going through the samples might be helpful https://github.com/CartBlanche/MonoGame-Samples

Answer (score 3):

Not sure If I'm an appropriate person to answer this question but you can check that:

1. Game states

   Use state pattern for managing game states - it will make transition between states (like from menu to game started state etc.) and pausing/unpausing  easier - some kind of `GameStateManager` which call proper `IGameState`: `Update, Render, LoadContent` methods.
2. Game Camera

   Learn about transformation matrices and use game camera (`SpriteBatch.Begin` has one parameter called matrix). With game camera you can draw using "internal coordinate system" - that means all your drawing points are in "imaginary screen of resolution for example 1024x860" and later it could be scaled to fit user display. You write for one resolution and with few lines you can handle other resolutions.  Game camera could be also useful when you would like to rotate all your enemy objects (let say 1000 monsters) - instead of rotation each object one by one you just rotate your coordinate system (game camera). For more check: http://www.david-gouveia.com/portfolio/2d-camera-with-parallax-scrolling-in-xna/, http://www.david-amador.com/2009/10/xna-camera-2d-with-zoom-and-rotation/

Answer (score 1):

I've been using MonoGame for about 3 months now and have a simple "framework" that renders 3D and 2D objects.

I think the best way to get some sense of structure would be to have a look at Unity3D, which uses Scenes and GameObjects.

Keywords would be: Scenegraph, GameObject.